# In chat the search results per page message count is off-by-one

Tags: bug, chat, chat-search

If I use the search feature on chat the results are paged in batches of 50. At least that is what you think based on the parameters in the url:

`...?q=close&User=578411&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest`

in reality there are 51 messages rendered to the page. If you visit page two the last message of page 1 is the first message on page 2.

It is easier to repro and see if you fiddle with the url parameters:

[`.../search?q=close&User=578411&page=1&pagesize=1&sort=newest`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=close&User=578411&page=1&pagesize=1&sort=newest)

which shows this result for page 1:
[image: page 1 of the search result]
and this for page 2:
[image: page 2 of the search result]

If there is time could this be fixed please?